# Katalon performing nested Selenium WebDriver finds

Tags: selenium, katalon-studio

I am attempting to get all `<li>` in a specified `<ul>` in Katalon Studio. I am trying this via Selenium WebDriver. I have code like this :

```
// login with valid account
WebUI.callTestCase(findTestCase('ValidLogin'), [('shouldCloseBrowser') : false], FailureHandling.STOP_ON_FAILURE)

// get the driver
WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver()

// Loop over selection of each company, and assert that we land on respective dashboard
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

WebElement companyListContainer = driver.findElement(By.id('companyList')) 
// finds this element OK


List<WebElement> companies = companyListContainer.findElements(By.xpath('.//li'))
 // this failed

for (int i = 1; i <= companies.length; i++) {
    // click the test object
    driver.findElement(By.xpath('//ul[@id="companyList"]/li[' + i + ']')).click() 
    // implicitly wait 3 seconds
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // we better be at the Dashboard page
    // go back to "Company Select"
    WebUI.click(findTestObject('a_Company Select'))
    // wait three seconds again
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
}
```

and for some reason, even though there were `<li>`s on the page, the `List<WebElement>` is null, even though `companyListContainer` wasn't, and contained those elements. How do I fix this?

**The HTML**

looks like :

```
<ul id="companyList" class="list-group">

    <li class="list-group-item clickable " data--name="EzDine C2 - Michael" data--id="302">
        EzDine C2 - Michael
        <span class="list-check"><i class="fa fa-check text-success" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    </li>

    <li class="list-group-item clickable " data--name="EzDine Comp3 -Hos" data--id="303">
        EzDine Comp3 -Hos
        <span class="list-check"><i class="fa fa-check text-success" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    </li>

    <li class="list-group-item clickable " data--name="Test EZDine V2 Comp1" data--id="301">
        Test EZDine V2 Comp1
        <span class="list-check"><i class="fa fa-check text-success" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: If possible, can you add HTML ?

Comment: I'm about to update the question to include it

Comment: I just tested this and companies giving me count 3, only difference I've tried in C#

Comment: Are you able to try it from Katalon Studio?

Comment: /* Can you try the same use case, on stackoverflow.com, from Katalon, on the "Jobs" list, with the `<ul>` being a `.jobs` and the `<li>` being the individual jobs? */

Answer (score 0):

The error was because of the stupidest reason (that, somehow, Katalon failed to tell me): I was trying to access the `length` of a list; /* that member doesn't exist in `java.util.List`! */
I changed to `size()` and it worked.

Katalon is really flawed for not having alerted me of this; /* they said something about `null` not being defined, but not that I was attempting to access a member that didn't exist */